# The service is actually an init script but the system is managed by systemd warning

Tags: systemd, ansible, systemctl

After execute manually `systemctl start example.service` then it starts up but not as part of ansible automatically, while other applications with same config it starts up. What does `The service is actually an init script but the system is managed by systemd` warning meaning? The other apps what starts up doesnt have this warning.

Ansible script:

```
- name: Enable service
  service: name=example enabled=yes
```

Ansible log:

```
TASK [provision-app : Enable service] ***********************
Sunday 08 December 2019  17:25:42 +0000 (0:00:01.100)       0:00:28.007 ******* 
 [WARNING]: The service (example) is actually an init script but
the system is managed by systemd
```

service files:

```
/run/systemd/generator.late/example.service
/run/systemd/generator.late/runlevel5.target.wants/example.service
/run/systemd/generator.late/runlevel4.target.wants/example.service
/run/systemd/generator.late/runlevel3.target.wants/example.service
/run/systemd/generator.late/runlevel2.target.wants/example.service
```

.Service file:

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/rc.d/init.d/example
Description=SYSV: Application Suite
Before=runlevel2.target
Before=runlevel3.target
Before=runlevel4.target
Before=runlevel5.target
After=network-online.target
After=network.service

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/example start
```

systemctl status:

```
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/example; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the real answer to the OP but since Google brought me here for the same error message I'll post my findings here.

Ansible module `service` or `systemd` started failing with the same warning `The service (your_service_name) is actually an init script but the system is managed by systemd` and with a message `Service is in unknown state` when my kernel was updated to 5.8 (from 5.4).

It turns out you need to upgrade your systemd version to accomodate some changes. In my case on Ubuntu, systemd 245.4-4ubuntu3 is not working but 245.4-4ubuntu3.5 is (from focal-updates).

Quick check:

```
systemctl show sshd | grep ActiveState
Failed to parse bus message: Invalid argument
```

If you get the invalid argument output, update.

Source: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1853736